# android how to upload data to json

Tags: android, json

I wanna to upload image or comment or anything from my application to server(json). and it should be permantely stored in server(json)
How can I do that please give me answer with some sample code.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code to send your json to server and get response (if any).

```
private Void sendJsonGetAsynch() {
    Reader r;
    HttpClient httpClient = ConnectionUtil.getNewHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 10000);
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("your url");
    InputStream data = null;
    try
        String json = URLEncoder.encode("here goes your json string ", "UTF-8");
        StringEntity visitBeanStringEntity = new StringEntity(json);
        httpost.setEntity(visitBeanStringEntity);
        httpost.setHeader("json", "application/json");
        httpost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpost);
        if (response != null) {

            data = response.getEntity().getContent();
            r = new InputStreamReader(data);

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            Reader in = new BufferedReader(r);
            int ch;
            while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
                buffer.append((char) ch);
            }
            in.close();
            logger.info("Return :" + buffer.toString());
            return buffer.toString();
        } else {
            logger.error("Response was null");
            throw new Exception("JSON response was null");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: my json file already present in server & from that i retrieve data also. I want to upload data there.That means to an existing json file's array. How can i do that?

Comment: Json is used only to transport data between your app and server, not to store them anywhere. To create json from java objects (and java objects from json) use jackson or gjson or any other library (it's quite simple).

Comment: As far as I understand your problem you need to download data via json (code above). Translate it via some json library to java objects, modify them and send back to server (code above). But frankly it all depends on how your server is implemented.